# I want to fetch cost between January and December using case statement, now i am getting Null instead of cost here is my code below

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT  dbo.postst.cost as Cost2014,
 case when (dbo.InvNum.OrderDate) between '2014/01/01' and '2014/12/31' then dbo.Postst.Cost end as Cost2014
 from dbo.postst INNER JOIN dbo.invnum on dbo.invnum.autoindex = dbo.postst.accountLink
```

Comment: Raw data would be helpful in the question I think

Comment: Better you use alias name for tables so that there will be better readability

Answer (score 0):

Here is the technique I use for tracking down an issue like this:

```
SELECT  dbo.postst.cost as Cost2014,
dbo.InvNum.OrderDate,
 case when (dbo.InvNum.OrderDate) between '2014/01/01' and '2014/12/31' then dbo.Postst.Cost end as Cost2014
from dbo.postst 
left JOIN dbo.invnum on dbo.invnum.autoindex = dbo.postst.accountLink
```

So I add the column I am doing some kind of processing on to see the values I am returning.  Then I change the inner join to a left join (temporarily). Then when I run the select, I can usually see why they may not be meeting my expectations and why my query is not retuning the correct results.

In this case, you may not have any data in the right range or the join might be incorrect and thus no records are picked up at all.

What you have is a relatively simple query, If it more complex, I often use select * instead of the sepcific columns just to see if there is something in the other columns that is affecting the results. This is often the case when you have a one-many relationship and want to get only one record but are getting duplicates in the fields you selected.